# Strategy orders not executed on live bar

Tags: pine-script

Does anybody knows how to make strategy to execute entries on live bars too? because after applying it on chart, it only shows trades for historical bars (till last bar), but after last bar (at the moment of applying, when new bars come) it doens't execute new orders.

Comment: A strategy that works on historical data should normally work on real-time data too. Can you share more information that makes it easier to help you? There's not much go on now with your question.

Comment: You need to show a minimal working example. Because, on Tradingview strategies are calculated automatically on real-time data.